# Php how to associate contacts with account before it is created

Tags: php, database

I don't really know how to ask this question, but I can't be the only one that has encountered something like this.

I am building a CRM for sales. I am working on a "bid" module that basically adds a bid account to an already existing customer account.  Each bid can have one or more project addresses.  On the Create A Bid page, my client want the Project Addresses to be added in a popup then to be saved using ajax.  The problem is I need to associate the Project Addresses with the bid by the bid id. Would not be a problem except the bid has not been saved yet.

My thought was to just create the initial bid account in the database at the start, then update it when saving the record. But my client is afraid that his call center workers will sometimes start to create a bid, and never save it, putting a blank bid in the database and on the account. Ideas?

Comment: Store them in the sessions, create the address record with empty bid # and update the bid # after save, or use your original thought + a cleanup process to remove uncompleted bids after x days.

Comment: Update after save + clean up? Maybe add a flag in order to tell if the bid was successfully updated or not, then add the flag check in the bids retrievals.

Wish it helps!

Comment: Have 3 tables: customer, project_address, and bid. The bid table contains a customer ID and project_address ID, you add that entry when the user saves the bid.